# Zalenium: Access container files in java

Tags: java, linux, selenium, docker, zalenium

I am trying to verify if an excel file has downloaded into a remote linux machine. I have used docker and Zalenium to run the test and the excel file is downloaded in a docker container (node). I'm having trouble getting started with JSch to achieve this. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: i am facing the same problem

Comment: similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60967870/download-recorded-video-of-ui-test-case-from-zalenium-selenium