# Download recorded video of UI test case from Zalenium/Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, zalenium

I've setup a [Zalenium](https://opensource.zalando.com/zalenium/) in Kubernates (in the cloud not local minikube or anything else), It works perfectly and everything is OK.
When I run a test case with recordVideo capability on, Zalenium records the test and stores a video inside a container, I can access the video via Zalenium's dashboard, but I want to download the video programmatically (not by visiting the dashboard) by RemoteWebDriver or something else, the video's name is dynamically generated and it consists of sessionId (known) and a timestamp which makes it impossible to generate by client to construct a URL to the video file, 
I wonder if anyone has already experience with Zalenium and knows how to download the video ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround which it helps in my scenario, Zalenium exposes a Servlet (`DashboardInformationServlet`) which provides information about tests that have been done so far, this servlet returns a list of objects, each object describes the test and gives a path to the video recording of the test, the information is enough to automate further steps I need to take.

Comment: Exactly, that was the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the 'name' in the capabilities and which is basically your test name and you will find the video file in /tmp/videos/'name'.mp4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).